# Right click on Start Menu Items on Windows 7 64-bit doesn't work?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, start-menu, right-click

I installed Windows 7 64 bit. Earlier, I had the 32-bit Windows. After installing 64-bit Windows, right-clicking the Start Menu items doesn't bring up the context menu!
How do I fix this?

Comment: Hell! My W7 64bit works fine. I have context menu. But there are two items only. Do you really need it?

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Check mouse drivers maybe. I have been running Windows 7 since early beta on several machines and have never had this issue.

Comment: mouse drivers are all fine .. Earlier i had win 7 32 bit .. then i backed up all my settings, installed win7 64bit and then restored my settings!!! after that it didnt work!

Comment: When I Right click the Start menu, I do not see anything. This was caused after editing the Registry to remove the arrows from thev Desktop Icons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on Start then choose Properties. On Start Menu tab, choose Customize > check "Enable Context Menus and dragging and dropping". Click Ok then "Apply" > OK. That's it.